# jQuery .click() and ModalPopupExtender

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

On my ASP.NET Web Forms page, there is a `Panel` which is a modal popup (using `ModalPopupExtender` in the [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/)). Apparently, the jQuery [`.click(f)`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method does not work if the target control is in a popup. The following code works only if I move the CheckBox out of the popup:

```
$("#checkBox").click(function() {
  // do something
});
```

This is how the checkbox is declared on the server site:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkBox" Text="..." ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

I need to bind a handler to the checkbox, while in the panel. Does anybody habe a hint for me?

Matthias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how the popups are implemented within the AJAX Control toolkit, but I suspect that the controls are added to the popup dynamically. 
If that is the case, you should do this (assuming you're not using an outdated version of jQuery):

```
$("#checkBox").live('click', function() {
  // do something
});
```

(See [here](http://api.jquery.com/live) to understand how this works.)

Try that and see if it works. If you're stuck with an old version of jQuery, I recommend using the LiveQuery plugin.

Comment: They are (statically) rendered into a `div` which is shown/hidden via `display` CSS attribute. Your solution, however, perfectly solves the problem. Thank you!